# How to show tick marks in spark HSlider / VSlider in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I want to show tick marks in HSlider and VSlider in flex. If i am using mx:HSlider or mx:VSlider there is option to show tickmarks, but i am using spark components in my project as skinning is required and i want to show tick marks in sliders. Anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: try this http://forums.adobe.com/message/2486158